# Convert a list with quotes into a python list

Tags: python

```
list_example = "['0101612-0', '0101611-2', '0101610-4', '0101608-8', '0101607-0', '0101606-2', '0100786-3', '0100784-8', '0100783-0', '0100782-2', '0100781-4', '0100780-6', '0100779-8', '0100778-0', '0100777-2']"
```

I want to convert above into this:

```
list_example = ['0101612-0', '0101611-2', '0101610-4', '0101608-8', '0101607-0', '0101606-2', '0100786-3', '0100784-8', '0100783-0', '0100782-2', '0100781-4', '0100780-6', '0100779-8', '0100778-0', '0100777-2']
```

I tried following: `list_example = list_example.split(',')` which resulted to:

```
["['0101612-0'",
 " '0101611-2'",
 " '0101610-4'",
 " '0101608-8'",
 " '0101607-0'",
 " '0101606-2'",
 " '0100786-3'",
 " '0100784-8'",
 " '0100783-0'",
 " '0100782-2'",
 " '0100781-4'",
 " '0100780-6'",
 " '0100779-8'",
 " '0100778-0'",
 " '0100777-2']"]
```

Which is messy to extract the values from.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html):

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = "['0101612-0', '0101611-2', '0101610-4', '0101608-8', '0101607-0', '0101606-2', '0100786-3', '0100784-8', '0100783-0', '0100782-2', '0100781-4', '0100780-6', '0100779-8', '0100778-0', '0100777-2']"
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
['0101612-0', '0101611-2', '0101610-4', '0101608-8', '0101607-0', '0101606-2', '0100786-3', '0100784-8', '0100783-0', '0100782-2', '0100781-4', '0100780-6', '0100779-8', '0100778-0', '0100777-2']
```

You can do it with `split` & `strip` too but it's bit more complex:

```
>>> [x.strip('\'') for x in s.strip('[]').split(', ')]
['0101612-0', '0101611-2', '0101610-4', '0101608-8', '0101607-0', '0101606-2', '0100786-3', '0100784-8', '0100783-0', '0100782-2', '0100781-4', '0100780-6', '0100779-8', '0100778-0', '0100777-2']
```

Comment: When you see a commonly-asked question, you can vote to close it as a duplicate. This helps the site maintain its quality and avoid fragmentation.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest (and probably most dangerous) way to do this is to use `eval`.

```
my_list = eval(list_example)
```

This code should return a list object full of strings.  Warning:  make sure the user can't input any malicious code inside of `list_example`!